# How can I get the localized value for Program Files folder with wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I use the ProgramFiles64Folder in wix to get the Program Files folder
in my installer.

The problem is it displays c:\Program Files instead of c:\Programmes
which is the french value.

It still installs to the correct folder but my users are asking why
they don't see the french value.

I have opened the msi with orca and i see ProgramFiles64Folder so
I guess it's not a wix specific issue but a windows installer one.

How can I get the localized value for Program Files folder with wix ?

Comment: Can you share an MSI log file?  ProgramFiles64Folder should be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the Win32 file system path, which is no longer localized beginning with Windows Vista. What you want instead is the shell's localized *display path*.

Windows Installer displays only file system paths in its build-in UI. I'm not exactly sure about WiX Burn UI, but most likely it will also show the file system path only.

You could write a DLL custom action (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368075(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html) reference) to get the display path.

The following is C++ code of a simple console application that demonstrates how to convert a file system path to a display path. In a custom action you would call [`MsiGetProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370134(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the value of the directory property that contains the installation path, convert it to a display path using code similar to my example and finally call [`MsiSetProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370391(v=vs.85).aspx) to assign the display path to another property that you would show in the UI.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>    // Shell API
#include <Propkey.h>   // PKEY_* constants
#include <atlcomcli.h> // CComPtr
#include <atlbase.h>   // CComHeapPtr
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// Convert a filesystem path to the shell's localized display path.
HRESULT GetDisplayPathFromFileSystemPath( LPCWSTR path, PWSTR* ppszDisplayPath )
{
    CComPtr<IShellItem2> pItem;
    HRESULT hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName( path, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS( &pItem ) );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;
    return pItem->GetString( PKEY_ItemPathDisplay, ppszDisplayPath );
}

int main()
{
    CoInitialize( nullptr );  // TODO: check return value
    _setmode( _fileno( stdout ), _O_U16TEXT );  // for proper UTF-16 console output

    LPCWSTR fileSystemPath = L"C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures";
    CComHeapPtr<WCHAR> displayPath;
    if( SUCCEEDED( GetDisplayPathFromFileSystemPath( fileSystemPath, &displayPath ) ) )
    {
        // Output the localized display path
        std::wcout << static_cast<LPCWSTR>( displayPath ) << std::endl;
    }

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

The only really important code here is in the `GetDisplayPathFromFileSystemPath()` function. It calls [`SHCreateItemFromParsingName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762134(v=vs.85).aspx) to create an [`IShellItem2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761130(v=vs.85).aspx) object from a file system path. From this object it retrieves the value of the property [`PKEY_ItemPathDisplay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760776(v=vs.85).aspx), which contains the display path we are interested in.

Comment: would have never find this myself thanks a lot for the detailed answer